# Pandas: Modify a particular level of Multiindex, using replace method several times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I am trying to use the replace method several times in order to change the indeces of a given level of a multiindex pandas' dataframe.

As seen here: [Pandas: Modify a particular level of Multiindex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150346/pandas-modify-a-particular-level-of-multiindex), @John got a solution that works great so long the replace method is used once.

The problem is, that it does not work if I use this method several times.
E.g.

```
df.index = df.index.set_levels(df.index.levels[0].str.replace("dataframe_",'').replace("_r",' r'), level=0)
```

I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `str.replace` twice:

```
idx = df.index.levels[0].str.replace("dataframe_",'').str.replace("_r",' r')
df.index = df.index.set_levels(idx, level=0)
```

Another solution is converting [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html) and then [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) by dictionary:

```
d = {'dataframe_':'','_r':' r'}
idx = df.index.levels[0].to_series().replace(d)
df.index = df.index.set_levels(idx, level=0)
```

And solution with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html), if large data and performance is important:

```
d = {'dataframe_':'','_r':' r'}
s = df.index.levels[0].to_series()
df.index = df.index.set_levels(s.map(d).fillna(s), level=0)
```

---

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':['dataframe_','_r', 'a'],
        'B':[7,8,9],
        'C':[1,3,5],

}).set_index(['A','B'])

print (df)
              C
A          B   
dataframe_ 7  1
_r         8  3
a          9  5

d = {'dataframe_':'','_r':' r'}
idx = df.index.levels[0].to_series().replace(d)
df.index = df.index.set_levels(idx, level=0)
print (df)
      C
A  B   
   7  1
 r 8  3
a  9  5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great and extensive answer! A learnt very useful stuff, and pardon my stupid initial question, as I missed that ".str" before the second replace method.

Comment: I accepted it: sorry, I am rather new at this and was not aware about this feature. Thanks again! :)

Comment: `map` soln works for multiple levels too, and also with level names: `df.index = df.index.set_levels((s1.map(d1).fillna(s1), s2.map(d2).fillna(s2)), level=('lev1', 'lev2'))`