# How to consider foreign key relations in (pandas) pivot_tables?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, powerpivot

With PowerPivot in Exycel I am able to

a) create a data model that consists of several connected tables (see example below)

b) create a pivot table based on that model

For display, the pivot table does not use id (=integer) values but the corresponding string values as row/column headers.

With pandas I could

a) load and join those related tables
b) create a pivot table based on the joined table

```
pivot_table = pandas.pivot_table(
    joined_table,
    index=["scenario_name"], #entries to show as row headers
    columns='param_name',          #entries to show as column headers
    values='value',          #entries to aggregate and show as cells
    aggfunc=numpy.sum,       #aggregation function(s)
)
```

However, with huge tables, I would expect it to be more efficient, if the pivot_table operates
on the non-joined data table and applies the string values only for result display.

=> **Is there a convenient way to consider foreign key relations when using
pandas `DataFrame` and `pivot_table` ?**

I would expect something like

```
pivot_table = pandas.pivot_table(
    {"data": data_table, 
     "scenario": scenario_table, 
     "param": param_table
    },
    index=["scenario:name"], #entries to show as row headers
    columns="param:name",    #entries to show as column headers
    values="data:value",          #entries to aggregate and show as cells
    aggfunc=numpy.sum,       #aggregation function(s)
)
```

=> **If not, are there some alternatives libraries to pandas that could handle related tables as source for pivot tables?**

*Small example table structure:*

---

```
table "data"
id scenario_id param_id value
1  1           1        100
2  1           2        200
```

---

```
table "scenario"
id name
1  reference
2  best_case
```

---

```
table "param"
id name
1  solar
2  wind
```

---

`scenario_id` of table `data` points on `id` of table `scenario`

`param_id` of table `data` points on `id` of table `param`

*Another example with some more columns:*

[image]

Comment: Pivot as usual and replace the values of index/column names?

Comment: Yes. I did not want to reinvent the wheel and hoped that there would already exist some solution. Otherwise I would have to manually adapt the multi-index and headers of the resulting data frame, looking up the meaning of the ids in the corresponding tables. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150346/pandas-modify-a-particular-level-of-multiindex