# Access individual levels of multi index pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I would like to transform the date level in my multi index but I am not sure how to access that one level without affecting the other level. This is what I am doing:

```
pipeline_output.index=pipeline_output.index.get_level_values(0).tz_convert('US/Eastern')
```

This removes the other index obviously so I am left only with date. Is there a way to change this, so that this transformation only applies to level=0?

Another approach I took was this:

```
 pipeline_output.index.get_level_values(0)=pipeline_output.index.get_level_values(0).tz_convert('US/Eastern')
```

Which produces an error, but it seems to work on the right hand side but not on the left hand side.

EDIT: The approach below has worked (thanks Peter for the suggestion):

`pipeline_output.index=pipeline_output.index.set_levels(pipeline_output.index.levels[0].tz_convert('US/Eastern'),level=0)`

Comment: You might try messing around with the `set_levels` or `set_labels` methods.

Comment: those seem to be more for changing the name of the index column. I am trying to indicate that I would like to change only level 0, which works on the right hand side but not on the left hand side.

Comment: might it be possible just to use reset_index() > transform > set_index()

Comment: @Tartaglia, looks like `set_levels` is one way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629095/multiindex-and-timezone-frozen-list-error/26629643#26629643
Or you can rebuild the MultiIndex and apply your changes in a list comprehension: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150346/pandas-modify-a-particular-level-of-multiindex/41829331

Comment: Raphael, I thought about that too, but that seems cumbersome, shouldn't it be possible to do that directly?

Comment: Besides, the transform does only work on indexes it seems.

Comment: Peter, thanks for the suggestion. I took the set_levels approach and worked!!! I am posting it below my original post for future reference.

Comment: Tartaglia or @Peter either of you want to answer this? I had a similar problem, solved it through the links Peter gave, went back to answer and saw the EDIT at bottom of question. So now I feel cheeky answering and claiming my points, feels like stealing but happy to do it if neither of you want to...