# Changing indexes of a multi index df

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df with index1 year and index2 type.

```
                data
     year type  

     2017 A     1.23
          B     5.51
     2018 A     1.53
          B     0.89
```

I want to rename the index year so that it says Year 0 and Year 1.

I tried the following:

```
    index_years = []
    for i in range(len(df.index.levels[0])):
        index_years.append("Year " + str(i))
    df.index.levels[0] = index_years
```

But I get the following error:

```
ERROR GIVEN: 'FrozenList' does not support mutable operations.
```

Then  I tried this

```
    pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(x[0].apply("Year " + str(i) for i in range(len(df.index.levels[0]))), x[1]) for x in df.index])
```

But it gives an error `"int" boject is not subscriptible`

The result I want to obtain is:

```
                    data

     year    type  

     Year 0   A     1.23
              B     5.51
     Year 1   A     1.53
              B     0.89
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: Modify a particular level of Multiindex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150346/pandas-modify-a-particular-level-of-multiindex)

Comment: could you please update your question with the expected answer. It is difficult to understand what you mean by `rename the index year so that it says Year 0 and Year 1.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have do that indirectly, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629095) (by the way, this is a duplicate of other questions)

```
# remove 'year' and 'type' from index
df = df.reset_index()
# do changes to year
df.year = df.year.apply(lambda x: 'Year %i' %(x-2017))
# set 'year' and 'type'as indices
df = df.set_index(['year', 'type'])
```

Comment: @divakaivan could you please then add up vote the answer? Also, could you please clarify if the changes to the question are correct, i.e. if the expected result is right?

Comment: the exact code helped me and did what I said the question above

Answer (score 0):

There is a property called index.names that you can use to set the names. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'year':['2017','2017', '2018', '2018'], 
                   'type':['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'], 
                   'data':[1.23,5.51, 1.53, 0.89]
                 })
df = df.set_index(['year', 'type'])

# Here is the code to modify the DataFrame as you wanted
df = df.reset_index() #reset index so you can access the year as a column and have an integer index you can use
df.year = df.index.map(lambda x: f'year {x}') #map using a function to create new values for year that you need

df = df.set_index(['year', 'type']) #recreate the multilevel index
df
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this code changes the names of the indexes, i.e. year and type become year 0 and year 1. What I need is for 2017 to become Year 0 and 2018 to be Year 1